# how to restrict the addition and subtraction according to the list elements?

Tags: python, list

I have a list called `dispatch`, and in that list whenever there is a positive number that means charge, and whenever there is a negative number that means discharge.

```
dispatch = [12,23,34,45,-23,-23,-12,23,34,-54,-54,-67]
```

So the `initial charge` is 0 and I start adding the values of `dispatch` in the `initial charge` and there are lower and upper restrictions to this. The upper restriction is 50 and the lower restriction is 0.
The program that I wrote for this :

```
dispatch = [12,23,34,45,-23,-23,-12,23,34,-54,-54,-67]
charge = 0
soc = []
for i in dispatch:
    if i > 0:
        charge = min(charge + i, 50)# upper restriction 50
        soc.append(charge)
    else:
        charge = max(charge - i, 0)# lower restriction 0
        soc.append(charge)
print(soc)
```

output:

```
[12, 35, 50, 50, 73, 96, 108, 50, 50, 104, 158, 225]
```

but this is wrong.
my expected output was:

```
[12, 35, 50, 50, 27, 4, 0, 23, 50, 0, 0, 0]
```

can anyone help?

Comment: why exactly should the 5th value be `7`? That seems very random. Neither `50-23` nor `50+23` results in 7

Comment: I think u need to write ```charge=max(charge+i,0) ``` in the else part.

Comment: yes i have corrected the expected output

Comment: and even after changing the else condition, I won't get the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subtracting a negative value from `charge`. So, it becomes `charge - (-value)`. As, we know 2 negatives form a positive. So, it will add the two values and choose it because it will be greater than 0.

```py
...
    else:
        # Add i to charge
        charge = max(charge + i, 0)# lower restriction 0
        soc.append(charge)
```

Comment: I don't think this still gives OP's desired output

Answer (score 3):

Use mix of `max` and `min`:

```
soc = [0]
for i in dispatch:
    soc.append(min(max(soc[-1] + i, 0), 50))
soc = soc[1:]
print(soc)
```

Output:

```
[12, 35, 50, 50, 27, 4, 0, 23, 50, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
dispatch = [12,23,34,45,-23,-23,-12,23,34,-54,-54,-67]
charge = 0
soc = []
for i in dispatch:
    charge = min(charge + i, 50) if i > 0 else 0
    soc.append(charge)
print(soc)
```